# Android Studio Git->Add an existing file, lost history on repo

Tags: git, android-studio

I couldn't believe this happened, but here's what I face, please help:
I've been using default settings of git with Androis Studio. (no github). My project has been committed many times no problem.
Then this morning, I right-click my mainActivity.java (that of course has already been in repo and committed through many changelists no problem), context menu Git-> Add (ctrl-alt-A). [See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfBPf.png)

I clicked it out of curiosity, and nothing seems to be happening, which was what I expected, since it's already added since the beginning of the project last month, it should be no-op.

To my bewilderment, when I commit changes on this .java, it shows a completely new file! I tried "show history" of my project, this mainactivity.java is missing in all the dozens of commit history, as if it's never been born!

What the xxxx? Could folks please help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you but I can suggest you to use [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) it's 100% free and you have a great interface to see your changes and your file that have been deleted. Also, Android Studio works perfectly with it, once it's setup you just have to click Commit and Pull.